# Yup InferType optional properties

Tags: typescript, yup

This is an example of a Yup schema i have in order to fetch entities called Parcels

```
export const FindParcelsParamsSchema = Yup.object({
  cursor: Yup.number().optional(),
  pageSize: Yup.number().positive().integer().optional(),
});
```

every field is optional

and this is the Interface I try to generate for this schema:

```
export interface IParcelsFetchingParams extends Yup.InferType<typeof FindParcelsParamsSchema> { }
```

I believe i should be able to declare this variable :

```
let params: TParcelsFetchingParams = {};
```

but typescript won't stop rasing this error:

*`Type '{ cursor: undefined; pageSize: undefined; }' is missing the following properties from type...`*

unless i add all the fields as undefined

```
let x: TParcelsFetchingParams = {
  cursor: undefined,
  pageSize: undefined,
};
```

my tsconfigs are:

```json
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "strict": true
  }
```

So why am I exactly facing this problem, and how can I fix it?

I expect I can declare my variable as an empty variable or with one property without issues.

Comment: I'm facing this same problem and the question is only three hours old 

Answer (score 0):

Declare `FindParcelsSchema` as `let`, not `const`.

I'm not sure why this causes the effect it has, but it fixed the issue for me. See [docs here](https://github.com/jquense/yup) and note how all `yup.object`s are declared with `let` instead of `const`.